# How do I use string formatting to show BOTH leading zeros and precision of 3?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to represent a number with leading and trailing zeros so that the total width is 7 including the decimal point. For example, I want to represent "5" as "005.000". It seems that string formatting will let me do one or the other but not both. Here's the output I get in Ipython illustrating my problem:

```
In [1]: '%.3f'%5
Out[1]: '5.000'

In [2]: '%03.f'%5
Out[2]: '005'

In [3]: '%03.3f'%5
Out[3]: '5.000'
```

Line 1 and 2 are doing exactly what I would expect. Line 3 just ignores the fact that I want leading zeros. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The first number is the **total** number of digits, including decimal point.

```
>>> '%07.3f' % 5
'005.000'
```

**Important Note:** Both decimal points (.) and minus signs (-) are included in the count.

Comment: This also counts the minus sign!  bleh, unusually shoddy for Python IMHO

Comment: As python 3 f-string: `f"{5:07.3f}"`

Answer (score 16):

This took me a second to figure out how to do @nosklo's way but with the `.format()` and being nested.

Since I could not find an example anywhere else atm I am sharing here.

### Example using `"{}".format(a)`

## Python 2

```python3
>>> a = 5
>>> print "{}".format('%07.3F' % a)
005.000
>>> print("{}".format('%07.3F' % a))
005.000
```

## Python 3

More `python3` way, [created from docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples), but Both work as intended.

Pay attention to the `%` vs the `:` and the placement of the format is different in python3.

```python3
>>> a = 5
>>> print("{:07.3F}".format(a))
005.000
```

```python3
>>> a = 5
>>> print("Your Number is formatted: {:07.3F}".format(a))
Your Number is formatted: 005.000
```

### Example using `"{}".format(a)` Nested

Then expanding that to fit my code, that was nested `.format()`'s:

```
print("{}: TimeElapsed: {} Seconds, Clicks: {} x {} "
      "= {} clicks.".format(_now(),
                            "{:07.3F}".format((end -
                                               start).total_seconds()),
                            clicks, _ + 1, ((_ + 1) * clicks),
                            )
      )
```

Which formats everything the way I wanted.

### Result

```bash
20180912_234006: TimeElapsed: 002.475 Seconds, Clicks: 25 + 50 = 75 clicks.
```

### Important Things To Note:

> - @babbitt: The first number is the total field width.
> - @meawoppl: This also counts the minus sign!...

Answer (score 9):

[Edit: Gah, beaten again]

```
'%07.3F'%5
```

The first number is the total field width.